# Android studio does not see my phone

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

**when I click the run the android studio does not see my phone**.

Any suggestion ?

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you enable development mode form your Android device?

Comment: is this the first time running on device?

Comment: Is USB debugging enabled?

Comment: Yes I enabled.Yes this is the first time.

Comment: How could I enable USB debugging? Could you help me?

Comment: In settings > development options

Comment: Go to Developer Options on your phone and enable USB Debugging.

Comment: enable USB debugging + install nexus 5 drivers (it's quite easy, http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) . I had some troubles with it aswell, but it's quite easier after you have installed the drivers. Please do not forget to plug in the nexus 5 AFTER you have launched android studio, so that the IDE can detect the phone (my pc didn't the first time, for some unknown reasons) .

Comment: Thanks for the help the problem was about usb debug mode.Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are possibilities if device doest recognized by studio,

try doing :

1. not installing [Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)
2. configure the "Media Mode" in "Camera (PTP)" instead of "Media
   device (MTP)"
3. Go to settings/ developer settings/ allow USB debug mode

To change what your application defaults to when you click run or debug in Android Studio, go to **Run -> Edit Configurations**

Comment: Thanks for the help I was trying to apply the suggestions.So the problem was about USB debug mode.Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Glad that it helped you and thanks for appriciation.

Answer (score 0):

Kingoroot- Single application can be used for all Android mobiles to connect USB debugging.

Download Kingoroot from google.